# Model's embedding predictions gets slower after each batch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I've trained a neural network that would generate the input data's embedding. Training have done easily.

Now, I want to generate the embeddings of the dataset from the model. Currently, how I've implemented is that there is a `dataloader` for dataset which is passed to the `model` to generate the embeddings.Once, `model` generates the embeddings, it is stored in a numpy array.

```
model.eval()
FX      = np.zeros((1,300)) # embedding size is 300
print('\nGenerating Embeddings..')

    with torch.no_grad():

        for bi, data in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader)):

            ids            = data["ids"]
            mask           = data["mask"]
            token_type_ids = data["token_type_ids"]
            target         = data["targets"]        # This is 1-hot label row
            target         = target.squeeze(1)

            ids            = ids.to(config.device, dtype=torch.long)
            mask           = mask.to(config.device, dtype=torch.long)
            token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(config.device, dtype=torch.long)

            output         = model(ids, mask, token_type_ids)

            FX             = np.append(FX, output.detach().cpu().numpy(), 0)
```

`FX` is numpy array that stores the model's `output` which is the embedding.

Problem I'm facing is as epoch moves ahead, it gets slower solely due to storing the model output in FX. I’m also detaching the model output from the computation graph and then converting it into numpy array but still GPU memory keeps rising and epoch gets slower after batch by batch.

I tried commenting out `FX = np.append(FX, output.detach().cpu().numpy(), 0)` and I found epoch doesn’t get slowed down. It worked perfectly.

How can I store the embeddings from the model such that the epoch doesn’t get slower?

I've seen other questions where epoch was getting slower and all have suggested to remove the computation graph and then store it but that doesn't in my case.

Comment: Why don't you turn `FX` into a normal python list and make it a numpy array later? numpy arrays don't grow well like this, but python lists do.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to numpy arrays is quite slow. The faster way would be to use a native python list (which grows scalably) and convert it to a numpy array later.

```
model.eval()
FX      = []
print('\nGenerating Embeddings..')

    with torch.no_grad():

        for bi, data in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader)):

            ids            = data["ids"]
            mask           = data["mask"]
            token_type_ids = data["token_type_ids"]
            target         = data["targets"]        # This is 1-hot label row
            target         = target.squeeze(1)

            ids            = ids.to(config.device, dtype=torch.long)
            mask           = mask.to(config.device, dtype=torch.long)
            token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(config.device, dtype=torch.long)

            output         = model(ids, mask, token_type_ids)

            FX.append(output.detach().cpu().numpy())
# ...
FX = np.vstack(FX)
```